# define Java class in jsp pages and reuse them across different jsp pages

Tags: jsp

I defined class Test in test1.jsp

```
    <%! public final class Test{

    }
    %>
```

This class actually has implicity package names, for example if I include it in test2.jsp, the class name is org.apache.test2.Test or the like. 
Is there a way to define packaged class Test in test1.jsp so that I can reuse it and pass it across different jsps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Using a filter would promote re-use. If you wanted to include test1.jsp within test2.jsp you can use scriplets to include (or forward request) to test2.jsp. But underneath jsp will be compile to a servlet (class).